# Confusion about EQUALS option in Zsh

Tags: zsh

In my Zsh, the expression

```
echo =ruby
```

is expanded to

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

This is the "equals"-expansion of Zsh. According to the zsh man-page:

> If  a  word  begins with an unquoted `=' and the EQUALS option is set, the remainder of the word is taken as the name of a command.

Now, what confuses me, is that when I do a

```
setopt
```

the *equals* option does not show up, neither does a *noquals*. I also don't set it in startup files.

I wonder why it is set by default, and why *setopt* does not show me the state of this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setopt` doesn't show values that currently have their default value for the current emulation mode. In Zsh emulation mode, `EQUALS` is on by default, so `setopt` will show only `NO_EQUALS` if the option is turned off.

As to why it is on by default? The author felt it was a useful enough feature to warrant doing so. There's no "logical" reason for one choice or the other.